# Getting error "is incompatible with attribute tint (attr) color." while using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to set tint color on image at run time using Databinding

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppointmentEnable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src='@{paymentMethod.getActiveStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("DISABLE") ?  @drawable/ic_action_navigation_close : @drawable/ic_add_white_36dp}'
        android:tint='@{paymentMethod.getActiveStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("DISABLE") ?  @color/favourite_red : @color/green_light'/>
```

I am getting the error

```
 error: '@{paymentMethod.getActiveStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("DISABLE") ?  @color/favourite_red : @color/green_light' is incompatible with attribute tint (attr) color.
```

What is the probable solution to this issue.

Comment: You have missed closing '}' Add brace at the end : ... @color/green_light **}**'

Comment: oh yes. Thanks @ІгорОнек

Comment: You can upvote my comment if it was helpful for you ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just add } at last.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txtAppointmentEnable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src='@{paymentMethod.getActiveStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(`DISABLE`) ?  @drawable/ic_action_navigation_close : @drawable/ic_add_white_36dp}'
        android:tint='@{paymentMethod.getActiveStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(`DISABLE`) ?  @color/favourite_red : @color/green_light}'/>
```